# Sql Server negative SQL_DATA_TYPE

Tags: sql-server, azure

I'm working on TVP for Azure. Since `sys.sp_table_type_columns_100_rowset` are missing under Azure I trying to get view's columns with `sys.sp_table_type_columns_100`. Most of data there seems usable except negative and different `DATA_TYPE` and `SQL_DATA_TYPE`.

For example:

```
type   sp_table_type_columns_100_rowset   sp_table_type_columns_100

int    3                                  4
bigint 20                                 -5
ntext  130                                -10
```

What this negative numbers means and how to convert data types to `sp_table_type_columns_100_rowset` like type?

Answer (score 0):

So far after comparing results

DbTypeToOLEDBTypeArray: array[-11 .. 12] of Integer = (
  DBTYPE_GUID, DBTYPE_WSTR, DBTYPE_WSTR, DBTYPE_WSTR, DBTYPE_BOOL, DBTYPE_UI1, DBTYPE_I8, DBTYPE_BYTES, DBTYPE_BYTES, DBTYPE_BYTES, DBTYPE_STR,
  DBTYPE_EMPTY,
  DBTYPE_STR, DBTYPE_NUMERIC, DBTYPE_CY, DBTYPE_I4, DBTYPE_I2, DBTYPE_R8, DBTYPE_R4, DBTYPE_EMPTY {?}, DBTYPE_EMPTY {?}, DBTYPE_EMPTY {?}, DBTYPE_DBTIMESTAMP, DBTYPE_STR
); // decimal as currency